# UNION DE DOS CONSULTAS DE UNA MISMA TABLA EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema al querer realizar una union en dos consultas a una misma tabla:

**la consulta es la siguiente:**

```
DECLARE @Date DATE;
DECLARE @Line VARCHAR(40)
SET @Line = 'L-01';
set @Date = '2021-01-25';

SELECT CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType) AS [TOP DEFECTOS]
FROM tbRework WHERE Line = @Line AND
CAST ([DateNow] AS DATE) = CAST (@Date AS DATE)
GROUP BY CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType)
ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC

SELECT COUNT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType) AS [CANTIDAD DEFECTOS]
FROM tbRework WHERE Line = @Line AND
CAST ([DateNow] AS DATE) = CAST (@Date AS DATE)
GROUP BY CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType)
ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dando como resultado esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo realizar la union intente con JOIN pero me duplica los valores

```
DECLARE @Line VARCHAR(40);

SET @Line = 'L-01';
SET @Date = '2021-01-18';

SELECT 
a.[TOP DEFECTOS], b.[CANTIDAD DEFECTOS]
FROM 

(SELECT CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType) AS [TOP DEFECTOS], Component AS ComponentA
        FROM tbRework WHERE Line = @Line AND
        CAST([DateNow] AS DATE) = CAST(@Date AS DATE)
        GROUP BY CONCAT(Component , ' - ', ReworkType),Component
        ORDER BY COUNT(*)DESC
) AS a
JOIN 
(
SELECT COUNT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType) AS [CANTIDAD DEFECTOS],Component AS ComponentB
        FROM tbRework WHERE Line = @Line AND
        CAST([DateNow] AS DATE) = CAST(@Date AS DATE) 
        GROUP BY CONCAT(Component , ' - ', ReworkType),Component
) AS b ON ComponentA = ComponentB
ORDER BY b.[CANTIDAD DEFECTOS]
```

Resultado con este JOIN
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cadab renglón de cantidad de defectos se corresponde a un top de defectos?

Comment: Por cierto el código va como texto por favor y de paso agrega el join que intentaste

Comment: Asi es la cantidad que muestra en CANTIDAD corresponde al TOP justamente asi como se muestra

Comment: Agrega todo lo que te comento por favor

Comment: Listo, ya lo agregue.

Comment: Mira yo pensaría en lo siguiente quita el join, mueve el conteo de componentes de la segunda a la primer consulta y prueba así

Comment: No entiendo lo de eliminar el JOIN, ya hice el movimiento del conteo a primer consulta pero a que se refiere con eliminar el JOIN?

Comment: Que no lo ocupes

Comment: Quizá si cambias el orden del Group by : Component, Concat(...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad lo tienes casi resuelto en la primera consulta, donde tienes la agrupación, simplemente le tienes que decir que también cuente el número de datos por cada elemento agrupado

```
DECLARE @Date DATE;
DECLARE @Line VARCHAR(40)
SET @Line = 'L-01';
set @Date = '2021-01-25';

SELECT CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType) AS [TOP DEFECTOS],vCOUNT(*) AS [CANTIDAD DEFECTOS]
FROM tbRework WHERE Line = @Line AND
CAST ([DateNow] AS DATE) = CAST (@Date AS DATE)
GROUP BY CONCAT (Component, ' - ', ReworkType)
ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC
```

Comment: Genio! pude resolver este problema sin necesidad de utilizar JOIN muchisimas gracias